# Get average date in a selected query in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Is it possible to compute the average time of a user in a query?

Like:

```
reportedDate         userID
------------         ------
2018-03-17 00:27:15     1
2018-03-17 00:32:28     1
```

Comment: show the expected  result ..

Comment: seems strange  to me .. how with 5 minutes of diff  between two date you expect an average  result of 2 hours ?????

Comment: im sorry, my example was wrong.. just the actual date instead

Comment: do you want the difference between two dates ? or time ?

Comment: get average time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
SELECT
    `user_id`,
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`reportedDate `))), '%e %b %Y') as `averageReportedDate`
FROM `users`
GROUP BY `user_id`
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

With eloquent, you can use `User::avg('reportedDate')` or `User::where(...)->avg('reportedDate')` if you need a condition.

And if you want to group by user:

```
 User::groupBy('userId')->avg('reportedDate');
```