# Get average delivery time laravel from orders laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a e-commerce application. All delivered orders have a column "updated_at". I can with this column calculate average delivery time total delivered orders?

I have count all orders and column updated_at. What I need do, that calculate average time?

My code:

```
        $avgDelivery = Order::where('status', '=', '8')->avg('updated_at');
        $allDelivery = Carbon::parse($avgDelivery)->formatLocalized('%d'); //get avg days
```

But this return me `20180317368025.6000` and error: 
`DateTime::__counstruct(): Failed to parse time string... Unexpected character`

How I can get average time delivery with days correctly?

Comment: date of order updated, example: `2018-05-03 13:33:33`

Comment: how do you get the average delivery time by calculating the `updated_at` fields?

Comment: function `avg` get result average. Or not? How I can do?

Comment: Asking about the logic. Are you trying to find the average time taken for a order creation to delivery?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49326275/get-average-date-in-a-selected-query-in-laravel it is possible.

Comment: @ab_in I want trying to find the average time in days taken for a order updated_at to delivery. Order have status = 8, this is delivered order.

Comment: where do you save the order creation date?

Comment: You need to provide more info, if you want more help. Which are the possible contents of `updated_at`?

Comment: my suggestion would be take diffrence of order created date and order updated date fields of each record and calculate the average.

Comment: @ad_in you're right. How I can do it? I need get average time in days from orders delivered, which have status = 8.

Comment: @Jadasdas continue this discussion in your related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49421656/calculate-average-delivery-time-laravel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the average `datetime` of `updated_at` column

```
$avgDelivery = Order::where('status', '=', '8')
                    ->selectRaw('FROM_UNIXTIME(AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(updated_at))) as avgTime');
                    ->first();

$allDelivery = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($avgDelivery->avgTime)
                     ->formatLocalized('%d'); //get avg days
```

[References](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021947/how-can-i-make-an-average-of-dates-in-mysql)

Comment: `A non well formed numeric value encountered`

Comment: Could you do a `dd($avgDelivery)`  and post the details